# Stop services on app update

Tags: android, android-service, kill, ondestroy

I am developping an Android application that has an activity and several services.
My activity can be killed with no problem, but my services must not be killed for the app to work as intended.
For this reason, I do not stop my running services in the onDestroy of my main activity.

But when the user updates the application, the services are not killed and it causes errors.
How can I kill my services only when the user updates the application and not when the app is killed by Android to liberate memory?

Comment: "But when the user updates the application, the services are not killed and it causes errors" -- your process should be terminated when your app is updated, which therefore gets rid of your services as a side effect. "How can I kill my services only when the user updates the application and not when the app is killed by Android to liberate memory?" -- when your process goes away, for any reason, your services go away. In the memory case, depending upon what you returned from `onStartCommand()`, Android may automatically restart your service.

Comment: Ok but how come my Activity's onDestroy method is called when I update the app but not my Services onDestroy method?

Comment: `onDestroy()` is never guaranteed to be called, on any component.

Comment: Alright, thank you very much, I guess I just misunderstood my errors that I thought they were happening because my services were not killed.